# jQuery taking control over label's border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, border

My jQuery function looks like that

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {  
       $("label").css("border-bottom-color", "red");
    });  
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {  
       $("label").css("border-bottom-color", "#e6e6e6");
    });
```

1) I have a bunch of text inputs in my form. What I want to do is to change bottom border color of focused text boxes label (there is one label for every text box. And I want to change only focused text boxes label's border color). But my functions changes all labels' border colors at once. How to fix that problem?

2) I have 2 forms. with id's form1 and form2. I want to do same things to second form but color will be another. How to modify this func?

My forms are looking like that

```
<form id="form1">
 ...
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input name="fname" placeholder="please enter your first name" type="text" /> 
 ...
</form>

<form id="form2">
 ...
<label for="job">Your Job</label>
 ...
<input name="job" placeholder="please enter your job" type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/RvYca/3/

`label` tag's `for` attribute references to an `input`'s `id` attribute, not its `name`.
I moved the styles to css too.

Comment: how modify this func for input type text and password?

Comment: It's simple: $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]') Or use just $('input')... if you can.

Comment: I have 2 forms. with id's form1 and form2. I want to do same things to second form but color will be another. How to modify this func?

Comment: You have to modify the css only, see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RvYca/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use both CSS and JavaScript:

```
$('input:text, input:password, textarea').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).prev('label').addClass('focused');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).prev('label').removeClass('focused');
    });
```

And, in the CSS:

```
#form1 label.focused {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#form2 label.focused {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dRWY5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, use $(this) as your selector:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {  
   $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "red");
});  
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {  
   $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "#e6e6e6");
});
```

For question 2, do you mean, after the user has selected both items, in either order?  They can't both be in focus at the same time.

Comment: no no no... seems, you don't get my question. Please re-read.

Comment: there is one label for every text box. And i wanna change only focused text boxes label'sborder color

Comment: focused on 1 text box but changed color of all labels http://prntscr.com/3w300 and on blur event http://prntscr.com/3w30v

Comment: I have 2 forms. with id's form1 and form2. I want to do same things to second form but color will be another. How to modify this func?

Answer (score 0):

your selector is not specific enough for manipulating the css. You must be specific about which label you want to update. Something like this:

```
$('input[type="text"],textarea,input[type="password"]').focus(function() {  
   $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").css("border-bottom-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: how modify this func for input type text and password?

Comment: I've added additional selectors for you above.

Comment: I have 2 forms. with id's form1 and form2. I want to do same things to second form but color will be another. How to modify this func?